# Sed substitution with negative lookahead regex

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a use case to add attribute:: to field name_[0-9][0-9]: but some field already have attribute::, 
so i need to only add attribtue:: to name_[0-9][0-9]: that not followed by attribute::

I have tried this:

```
sed  -n  's/name_[0-9][0-9]:(?!attribute::)/&attribute::/p' out
```

Which i test on online regex debugger that the regex should be what i need, but actually this doesn't match if i give name_01:abc

Comment: `sed` doesn't use PCRE, so it doesn't have lookaheads.

Comment: @Barmar Then anyway to achieve this?

Comment: If you use GNU `sed`, I think you can recompile it with PCRE. Google it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Online regex debuggers" often don't tell you which precise regex dialect they test for; and if they tell you that, you need to know which dialect your `sed` supports.

You are trying to use a Perl regex feature which is not supported out of the box in any `sed` I am aware of, but of course, it's eminently well-supported in Perl.

```
perl -ne 's/name_[0-9][0-9]:(?!attribute::)/$&attribute::/ and print' out
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat file1
name_12:
name_34:attribute::
name_56:

$ sed '/:attribute::/n; s/name_[0-9][0-9]:/&attribute::/g' file1
name_12:attribute::
name_34:attribute::
name_56:attribute::
```

`n` : read the next line.

Comment: This is less precise in that it will look for `:attribute::` anywhere in the line.  The OP's problem doesn't look like it would be prone to this kind of corner case, but perhaps it should still be spelled out.